# Gathering data from a list of dates

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a long list of several thousand dates and times of people paying for a bill at a restaurant.

From this list I would like to try to understand:

What are the peak hours (eg: do  most people pay for the bill from 6-7PM)
And what are the peak days of the week (eg: most people pay for their bill on Wednesdays around 7PM)

Ideally I am looking for:

```
A way to visualize all the data over a 1 week period to see frequency over time
A way to visualize all the data over 1 day to see frequency over time
```

What tools / formulas could I use to answer my questions which are mainly: What time(s) is the restaurant at its busiest and what day(s) of the week is the restaurant at its busiest.

Comment: This question is a bit open-ended. What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a new column for each zoom level you want to show, e.g.:

- for day level chart formula to get day: `=WEEKDAY([@date],2)`, where `2` means that week start at Monday, and it's represented by number 1 (*with some more complicated formula you can even show day names*)
- for hourly chart formula is `=HOUR([@date])`

[image]

For preparing the chart the easiest way is a pivot chart:

- select Insert - PivotTable - PivotChart
- move day (or hour) to **axis fields**
- move date to **values** (make sure count of dates is calculated, and not average or sum)

[image]

*(my data is just 150 random dates, your real data will probably look better)*

Answer (score 0):

You might have to massage your data a little bit: add a column to pull the day's name (e.g. with formula `=text(A1,"ddd")`, then use a pivot table, put your dates / times in the row field, put them also in the data field as a Count, then group the dates in the row field to get the data you want.

You can also build a pivot chart using the same principle.